# A finite Monoid $M$ is a group if and only if it has only one idempotent element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monoid

Suppose that $(M,*)$ is a *finite* Monoid.

Prove that $M$ is a group if and only if there is only a single idempotent element in $M$, namely $e$.

One direction is obvious, because if $M$ is a group then $x^2=x$ implies $x=e$, but the other direction has been challenging me for over an hour, so I decided to ask it here.

Comment: Had a perfectly good answer and then I realized I'd missed the word "finite".

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, I wonder if the following holds: let $M$ denote an arbitrary (i.e. not-necessarily finite) commutative monoid. Then $M$ is cancellative iff the only idempotent is $e$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If $M$ is not a group, then there is an element $a \in M$ with no inverse.
Since $M$ is finite, there exists $n>m>0$ with $a^n=a^m$. You can now find a
power of $a$ that is idempotent, and it cannot be the identity, because $a$
has no inverse.

Suppose that $a^m=a^n$ with $n>m$, and hence $a^m = a^{m+(n-m)}$.

We claim that $a^m=a^{m + k(n-m)}$ for all $k \ge 0$, and we prove this by induction on $k$. We have seen that it is true for $k=0,1$. Then, for $k>1$, we have, using the inductive hypothesis for $k-1$,  $$a^{m + k(n-m)} = a^{m + (k-1)(n-m) + (n-m)} = a^{m+(k-1)(n-m)}a^{n-m} = a^ma^{n-m} = a^n = a^m$$
as claimed.

Now choose $k$ sufficiently large that $t := m + k(n-m) \ge 2m$. Then, multiplying both sides of $a^m=a^t$ by $a^{t-2m}$, we get $a^{t-m}=a^{2(t-m)}$, so $a^{t-m}$ is idempotent.

For example, if $a^7=a^9$, then $a^7=a^{15}$ and multiplying by $a$ gives $a^8=a^{16}$, so $a^8$ is idempotent.

Comment: I don't see how I can find a power of $a$ that is idempotent :/ Would you please go ahead with your argument?

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why "we can increase the $n$ while keeping $m$ constant" is implied by $a^{n}=a^{m+(n-m)}=a^{n+(n-m)}$, can't we always do that in general? and I don't see how that justifies our assumption that $n-2m \geq 0$. I see why we need $n-2m$ to be non-negative though (because $a$ is assumed to be non-invertible). I'd appreciate it if you try to explain those two statements.

Comment: The equation I wrote shows that you can always increase $n$ by $n-m$ so you can keep doing that and thereby increase it as much as you like. You need $n-2m \ge 0$ to justify multiplying by $a^{n-2m}$, because $a$ has no inverse.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I see why we need $n-2m \geq 0$ as I said, but I don't see why "we can increase the $n$ while keeping $m$ constant" implies $n-2m \geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see what it is that you don't understand. I did give an example. Let me give another one. Suppose initially that $m=23$, $n=27$. I can increase $n$ by $27-23=4$, so I can keep doing this and replace $n$ by 31, 35, 39, 43, 47.  Now $n-2m=47-46=1 \ge 0$.

Comment: OK, maybe I explained my confusion in a wrong a way. You say that since "we can increase the $n$ while keeping $m$ constant" we know that $n-2m \geq 0$. I agree with that because $m$ is constant and since it's finite by taking $n$ large enough finally we can find some $n$ such that $n \geq 2m$. I just don't know how to say it in a rigorous way mathematically, but it's only a minor problem I think.

Comment: Does it using contradiction? Where's the contradiction? Since there assume that $M$ is not a group.

Comment: @user795084 I have  written out the proof that some power of $a$ is idempotent more formally. Is it clear now?

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, it is clear. My question is, in your proof, there using if M is not group. We want to show M is group. Does there using a contradiction?

Comment: Yes, it is a proof by contradiction. I assumed that $M$  is not a group in the first line of the proof, and then I deduced that there is an idempotent element that is not equal to $e$. In other words, if $e$ is the only idempotent, then $M$ is a group.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a little clearer way to put it. Assume $x^a = x^{a+b}$ with $b >0$.
Then for any integers $u$, $k$, we have $x^{a+u} = x^{a+u + kb}$

So we need to find $u$ and $k$ such that $bk = a+u$. That's easy. Take $b$ such that $bk \geq a$ and let $u = bk-a$. Then $x^{a+u}$ is idempotent.