# Prove that in a finite monoid each element is invertible

Tags: monoid, idempotents

Let $(M,\circ)$ be a finite monoid. Suppose the identity element $e\in M$ is the only idempotent element. Then prove that each element in $M$ has inverse.
How can I prove this?

Comment: Let $a \in M$. Consider the set $\{e, a, a^2, \cdots \}$. Can this set be infinite?

Comment: This set is finite. From this we can say $a^{mn}$ is idempotent for some integers $m,n$, i.e., $a^{mn}\circ a^{mn}=a^{mn}$. Can I show the result from this?

Comment: @Mac If you can show what you say in your comment then you are ready. You are allowed to conclude that $a^{mn}=e$ since $e$ is unique as idempotent. Then $a^{mn-1}$ will serve as inverse of $a$. You could edit the proof of what you say in your comment so that it can be checked by others.

Comment: Duplicate of [A finite Monoid $M$ is a group if and only if it has only one idempotent element](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568034/a-finite-monoid-m-is-a-group-if-and-only-if-it-has-only-one-idempotent-element?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Let $a$ be an element of a finite monoid.

Then $n>0$ and $k>0$
exist with $a^{n+k}=a^{n}$, leading to $a^{m+kr}=a^{m}$ for $m\geq n$
and $r\geq0$.

Choose some $r$ such that $kr\geq n$ and note that
$a^{kr}$ is idempotent.

If identity $e$ is unique as idempotent
then $a^{kr}=e$, showing that $a^{kr-1}$ serves as inverse of $a$.