# Prove that in a finite monoid there exists $m > n$ such that $a^m = a^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, semigroups, monoid

Let $(M, \cdot, e)$ be a finite monoid. For $a \in M$ and some integer $n$, show there exists an integer $m >n$ such that $a^n = a^m$.

I've seen this conclusion used in many other questions, such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048598/prove-that-in-a-finite-monoid-each-element-is-invertible?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568034/a-finite-monoid-m-is-a-group-if-and-only-if-it-has-only-one-idempotent-element), and I understand that the set $\lbrace e, a, a^2, ...\rbrace$ is finite, but I am still confused on how this explains the existence of the integer $m$.

Comment: Such application of the Pigeonhole principle of the set of powers in a finite monoid occurs here in *many* places, e.g. see the linked dupes (and their links).

Comment: Those duplicates are for groups only, @BillDubuque.

Comment: @Shaun **Not true**. The linked dupes use *exactly* the same pigeonhole argument as here. The argument is applied in many contexts (monoids, (semi)groups, rings, etc) but it is exactly the same argument in all cases - see [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque: not directly related to the discussion here though, do you consider one should close *all* but one question under the tag [`partial-fractions`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-fractions) as "duplicate" since they are essential *one* single abstract technique?

Comment: @user1046533 Dupe evaluation depends on the question and the potential dupe targets that currently exist. But this is not the proper place to discuss such meta matters.,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This follows from the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle): since there is infinitely many potential powers of $a$, each of which in the monoid (by closure), but only finitely many elements of the monoid, there must exist at least two powers of $a$ that are the same, simply because there is no other place for the infinitely many potential powers to go.

The pigeons are the potential powers of $a$; the pigeonholes are the elements of the finite monoid.

Comment: Is there any way to state this formally? for example if I have $x^n$, is there some $k$ such that $x^n = x^{n+k}$?

Comment: Yes, @RMG. Use the statement of the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: Hang on, @RMG. There exist some finite monoids for which there exists a power $x^a$ of an element $x$ such that $x^a\neq x^{a+b}$ for all $b\in\Bbb N$; they're finite, cyclic monoids that are not groups. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) for details.

Comment: @RMC They're also called *monogenic semigroups with a one* and denoted $M(m,r)^1$, were $m$ is the smallest natural number such that the generator to the $m+r$ is the same are that to the $m$, where $r$ is the smallest natural number. Note that $M(1,q)^1$ is simply the cyclic group of order $q$.

Comment: @Shaun why this answer get $-3$ Downvote?

Comment: Supposedly, the question has a duplicate, @LostinSpace.

Comment: @Shaun  Ok. Sir.