# Let $(G,*)$ be a finite semigroup with identity. Prove that $G$ is a group iff $G$ has only one element $a$ such that $a^2=a$.

Tags: group-theory, semigroups, monoid

Let $(G,*)$ be a finite semigroup with identity. Prove that $G$ is a group iff $G$ has only one element $a$ such that $a^2=a$.

For the right direction, since $G$ is a group with identity, then there exists $a=e_G$ i.e. $a^2 = a$. Isn't it?

For the left direction, what should I do?

Comment: If $G$ has an identity $e$ then $e^2 = e$ always, right? So then any semigroup with identity that isn't a group (e.g. the nonnegative integers with addition) forms a counterexample.

Comment: Can you add your semi group definition

Comment: See here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140197/prove-that-a-finite-semigroup-g-with-identity-is-a-group-if-and-only-if-g-contai?rq=1

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Yes, it's right. For the counterexample, I still not got it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I still confusing with that. Can you give a different approach?

Comment: @BrienNavarro Semigroup is a math system $(G,*)$ where $*$ is assosiative.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer The question is about finite semigroups.

Comment: Why closed? ${}{}$

Comment: Because the identical question  was asked previously.

Comment: But I still not got it.

Comment: This user has not understood the answer to the given question : request to reopen. Having said that , what did you not understand in the given answer? You can also see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568034/a-finite-monoid-m-is-a-group-if-and-only-if-it-has-only-one-idempotent-element?rq=1) where the language is a little different but the idea is very clear. Also, note that there won't be too many different answers, because the only way to work is to produce an example of an element $x$ such that $x^2=x$ so then you can say $x=e$, and the best way to do is via powers.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Showing that if there exist an idempotent, then $G$ is a group.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, I have seen that previously. But, does it proved the left direction?

Comment: The other direction is clear , since if $a^2=a$ then multiply by $a^{-1}$ on both sides to give $a=e$, so in a group there is only one idempotent.

Comment: No, I mean the left direction.

Comment: @user795084 Yes, it proves the left direction (sorry for the direction confusion). An idempotent element is one such that $x^2= x$, so basically your question is : a semigroup is a group iff there's a unique idempotent. The attached post proves that if there's a unique idempotent then the semigroup is a group.

Comment: Got it right now. Thanks yow!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Rather than just repeating the same question, I believe the recommended procedure is to add a comment to the answer to the previous question requesting clarification. In any case, the poster needs to say exactly what they do not understand.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, I will rescind the vote. Actually I cannot, but thank you for that message, I made a mistake on this one.