# Let $(S,*)$ be a finite semigroup with identity. Prove that $S$ is a group iff $S$ has only one element $x$ such that $x^2=x$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, semigroups, monoid, finite-semigroups

Let $(S,*)$ be a finite semigroup with identity. Prove that $S$ is a group iff $S$ has only one element $x$ such that $x^2=x$.

**Attempt:** Does this approach true?

$(\Rightarrow)$
Let $S$ be a group. Denote $e_S$ be an identity element in $S$. Clearly, $e_S$ is idempotent since $e_S^2 = e_S$.
Suppose that there is another idempotent in $S$, say $x$. Then, $x^2 = x$. So,
\begin{equation*}
x^2=x \Leftrightarrow x^{-1}x^2 = x^{-1}x \Leftrightarrow x = e_S.
\end{equation*}
Hence, $x=e_S$. Thus, the only idempotent in $S$ is $e_S$.

$(\Leftarrow)$
First, to show for any $x \in S$, there exist $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $x^n$ is idempotent. I found this proof in the ProofWiki. Next, since the only idempotent in $S$ is $e_S$, then $x^n$ must equal to $e_S$. I have proved this already. But, I am still confused. If $n=2$, then $a^2 = e_S$ i.e. the inverse of $a$ is itself.
But, what about $n=3$? $a^3=e_S$, does it implies that the inverse of $a$ is $a^2$?

Comment: How do you know that $x$ has an inverse in $S$?

Comment: The inverse is $x^{n-1}$ right?

Comment: Cf [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3990068/104041).

Comment: @user795084 ahh sorry I missed the fact that $S$ is a group here

Comment: @Shaun I know. I just ask for the correction of my attempt.

Comment: $a^2 = e_S$ and $a^3 = e_S$, right?

Comment: @AnikBhowmick Ohhh. I make a small mistakes. Yes, you're true.

Comment: Then definitely we can say that $a^2$ is the inverse of $a$. Afterall that's the definition of inverse. The approach is perfect.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick Okay, thanks yow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in S$. Since $S$ is finite, there exist $a$, $d> 0$ such that
$$x^a= x^{a+d}$$

Now you can show easily by induction that
$$x^b = x^{b+ m d}$$

whenever $b\ge a$, and $m\ge 0$ integer. Let us choose $b\ge a$, and $m d$ such that they are both equal.  ( for instance, take $b = \operatorname{lcm}(a,d)$). Then we get
$$x^{b} = x^{b+b}$$
or $x^b= (x^b)^2$.  Therefore, $x^b$ is idempotent, so it must be $e$.
We conclude $x^{b-1} = x^{-1}$.

Comment: This is guarantee that every $x$ in $S$ has an inverse, right?

Comment: @user795084: correct!

Comment: Where does the $m$ come from, after the induction?

Comment: @Chris Custer:  Oh, first you do induction on $b$.  Then induction on $m$.  You need both $b$ and $m$ in order to make $b$ and $m d$ equals.  Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Oh.  Should have seen that.  Pretty slick.