# In a finite monoid (M, $\circ$) if the identity element $e$ is the only idempotent element, prove that each element of the monoid is invertible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monoid, binary-operations, quasigroups

> In a finite monoid (M, $\circ$) if the identity element $e$ is the only idempotent element, prove that each element of the monoid is invertible.

As the set $M$ is finite, $\exists$ $y \in M$, s.t $y \circ a = e$ $\forall a \in M$.

Similarly, we have $x \in M$, s.t $a \circ x = e$ $\forall a \in M$.

Now, we consider:

$a \circ x=e \implies y \circ (a \circ x) =y \circ e \implies (y \circ a)\circ x=y \implies x=y $ [by associative property of monoids]

Hence, for every $a \in M$, $\exists x \in M$ s.t $x \circ a=a \circ x = e$; i.e, every element is invertible.

> Now, my question is, is this at all the correct approach towards the solution?

Evidently, if $a \circ a=a$, then $y \circ a= (y \circ a) \circ a= e \circ a= a$ which is ultimately $a=e$
But does this imply that every $ y \circ a=e $ and $ a \circ x=e$ has a solution?

> [ Alternative form of the question: If a Monoid is a Quasigroup, then it is a Group (also kindly justify the alternative form of the question)]

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/568034/75923) might help.

Comment: I want someone to verify this approach...

Comment: How do you come to the statement that $y\in M$ must exist with $ya=e$?

Comment: This is what I need to show. If I can show, that $e$ has a pre image (y,a) then it is done

Comment: I would like to see proof that if a monoid is a quasigroup, then it is a group, please.

Comment: Hey, just did the proof. As you know, it is hard to type up the whole thing, so please consider  looking up the image: https://i.imgur.com/dqFLizr_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium

Comment: If you spot any mistake, please tell.

Comment: The sentence "As the set $M$ is finite, $\exists$ $y \in M$, s.t $y \circ a = e$ $\forall a \in M$" does not make sense. First, the quantifiers are misplaced. Secondly, the conclusion is wrong. I am voting for closing your question as unclear.

Comment: That was my approach. I may be or may not be wrong. Please do read the entire question. I have placed the question regarding my own doubt at the latter part.

Comment: See [quasigroups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup) for an answer to your alternative form of the question.